# Renderizar WebForm no ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Preciso chamar um WebForm a partir de uma Action no *controller*, li muita coisa na internet mais não consegui fazer funcionar.

Eu segui o exemplo [nesse link](http://vadimdev.blogspot.com.br/2011/01/rendering-aspnet-webform-via-mvc-action.html), onde pede para trocar a herança do WebForm `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage`, se eu não troco da erro informando que a herança deveria ser de `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage`, se eu troco da o erro abaixo.

[image: SS]

Comment: Eu alterei o WebForm por uma pagina ASP.NET MVC4(ASPX) e deu certo, o problema agora é que quando tento passar os parâmentros ele da o seguinte erro: O objeto de controle visualizador está no modo somente leitura

Comment: Qual o motivo de você ter que necessariamente usar um Web Form com o MVC?

Comment: Preciso renderizar relatórios que estão em um servidor do Reporting Services, e não encontrei nada no MVC pra isso, no WebForms tem o report viewer, funcionou certinho, só preciso agora conseguir chamar essa pagina da minha action.

Comment: Você pode chamar uma relatório do Report Builder pelo *Controller* MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Como não consegui renderizar pelo controller, descobri que é possível chamar o relatório hospedado no Reporting Services com JavaScript.

```
javascript: void (window.open('http://srv-teste/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Compras/Pedido&rs:Command=Render&param1=10&param2=20&rc:Parameters=Collapsed', '_blank'))
```

A opção *rc:Parameters=Collapsed* faz com que o prompt de parâmetros fique minimizado.

Comment: Essa forma não é bem o jeito que é feito em MVC. O correto é chamar as classes do *Report Builder* dentro do *Controller*.

Comment: Não consegui fazer desse jeito, pesquisei bastante e não consegui achar uma forma de fazer pelo controller, na verdade já estou a quase 1 semana com isso, se você já tiver feito isso e puder postar o código, ou se você tiver algum link que me ajude.

Comment: Eu tinha um exemplo, mas era um código de cliente, e eu não trabalho mais com ele. Se eu conseguir alguma coisa posto pra você.

Comment: Ok muito obrigado.